# finding solutions in matlab within interval for multiple variables

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have a code in matlab with a system of 6 equations and 6 variables. I want to solve the equations using the command vpasolve. the 6 variables are t11,t12,t13,t21,t22,t23.

> Is there a way to define a range for the solution for each of the 6 variables?

For example, I want to define the following ranges:

t11 should be between 10 to 50

t12 should be between 20 to 40

t13 should be between 10 to 50

t21 should be between -30 to -10

t22 should be between -10 to 50

t23 should be between -20 to 0

(and anything outside the range I don't want to get as a solution even if it solves the equation).

here is the matlab code with the equations that I want to solve:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

syms t11 t12 t13
syms t21 t22 t23  

eq1 = ((8922777075240195*t11)/9007199254740992 - 30)^2 + (96876011531181065287337706581037*t11^2)/5192296858534827628530496329220096 == (244*t21^2)/15869 + ((125*15869^(1/2)*t21)/15869 - 30)^2;
eq2 = (12284794394556242997808640319605*t12^2)/1298074214633706907132624082305024 + ((4482238245702333*t12)/4503599627370496 - 30)^2 == (244*t22^2)/15869 + ((125*15869^(1/2)*t22)/15869 - 30)^2;
eq3 = (45861658983305836864232546144709*t13^2)/2596148429267413814265248164610048 + ((1115910933745515*t13)/1125899906842624 - 30)^2 == (244*t23^2)/13469 + ((115*13469^(1/2)*t23)/13469 - 30)^2;
eq4 = ((8922777075240195*t11)/9007199254740992 - 30)*((4482238245702333*t12)/4503599627370496 - 30) - (33484849241113011368045542420311*t11*t12)/2596148429267413814265248164610048 == ((125*15869^(1/2)*t21)/15869 - 30)*((125*15869^(1/2)*t22)/15869 - 30) - (244*t21*t22)/15869;
eq5 = (282621115563350270054313878343*t12*t13)/2596148429267413814265248164610048 + ((1115910933745515*t13)/1125899906842624 - 30)*((4482238245702333*t12)/4503599627370496 - 30) == ((115*13469^(1/2)*t23)/13469 - 30)*((125*15869^(1/2)*t22)/15869 - 30) + (44*13469^(1/2)*15869^(1/2)*t22*t23)/213739561;
eq6 = ((8922777075240195*t11)/9007199254740992 - 30)*((1115910933745515*t13)/1125899906842624 - 30) - (23445242923211415885353539155021*t11*t13)/5192296858534827628530496329220096 == ((115*13469^(1/2)*t23)/13469 - 30)*((125*15869^(1/2)*t21)/15869 - 30) - (44*13469^(1/2)*15869^(1/2)*t21*t23)/213739561;

eqs = [eq1; eq2; eq3; eq4; eq5; eq6];
fprintf('Trying to solve the equations\n');
[t11_sol,t12_sol,t13_sol,t21_sol,t22_sol,t23_sol] = vpasolve(eqs,
[t11,t12,t13,t21,t22,t23])
fprintf('Finished solving the equations\n');
```

These are the current solutions:

```
t11_sol =

                              0
24.829703667085709792452797768139
-1714.7919752112047717253468263447
28.624266796914077249128523842231
15.001105796927906039239701205905
29.182011950632532749236452699932
30.474785714576283734530215094123
28.923418651100014933562154455752
29.862424638395540307680704064753


t12_sol =

                             0
32.391753131232910196633469521587
354.90128086865450529250280412221
32.669637807428363812347415161745
42.313425265860487109475748241225
35.77251360055612460919268449666
24.416997056184413504762966564475
32.200102042415756894425066902384
32.737813080348733797113244812407


t13_sol =

                              0
35.119449427391259768874643471793
-552.15221602531564524976910795555
32.333805237521337277174927681791
30.505819079433077866776605761009
-15.526604986133423038105829796394
30.503860894429235257295153122852
31.531326069780238017082050501478
30.689747387623702773113477696365


t21_sol =

                             0
34.950843287328625731811203211087
1774.2801076016584748700502034002
27.7309163513567839404453632282
44.586181192433735979455732171841
31.568950443178384558598040442723
31.645983484625245618431014726401
31.66220406339283719149782231373
31.4930547899057272421770424957


t22_sol =

                              0
28.719384780320222581709652667396
-295.26692316474930126337699876656
31.376616953264529835893660973616
17.528200591527370984833306720326
24.321988649431180122662011217513
34.695990177726174534054308234555
30.175898983099840329616659669692
31.493054789906158785302579540812


t23_sol =

                             0
24.379180250934429179070181825563
611.61273095943007252746244555442
32.247827126007408413822564919395
30.163585843012112112236997181374
74.982989890274977913497773016932
29.293932179042561861772077117988
28.046073521931256411622489184559
29.014005238849959150140190833736
```

I saw in matlab documentation that you can add a range but what I saw was for an equation of one variable. I didn't see anywhere equations with ranges for multiple variables. I also didn't see anywhere if it's possible or not.

> Can anyone show me how to add the ranges for each variable (if it's possible)?

Also, the given code returns 9 solutions for each variable. is there a default range for each of the variables? how can I know which variables it might miss? and how many solutions really exist? Is there a way to know that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for `vpasolve`, you should be able to specify the variable range as an N by 2 matrix, where N is the number of variables:

> If init_guess is a matrix with two columns, then the two entries of
>   the rows specify the bounds of a search range for the corresponding
>   variables. To specify a starting point in a matrix of search ranges,
>   specify both columns as the starting point value.

In your case:

```
varLimits = [10 50; 20 40; 10 50; -30 -10; -10 50; -20 0];
[t11_sol,t12_sol,t13_sol,t21_sol,t22_sol,t23_sol] = vpasolve(eqs,...
[t11,t12,t13,t21,t22,t23], varLimits)
```

Comment: Thanks. but it seems that it didn't help. since it still missed solutions inside the ranges. is there a way to ensure that the program will find ALL the solutions inside the ranges (even if it means that the calculations will take much longer)?

Comment: @David Did you find any solution to this problem as I am having a similar problem with 2 variables only.

Comment: I eventually installed Maple and used matlab with Maple's engine. it gave me all the possible solutions and didn't miss anything. then I could take the relevant solutions that I needed. Matlab by itself is not always working well with solving equations. It took me a while to notice that. Anyway, since you have only 2 variables you might not have any problem. I suggest that you post a question with your code and I'll try to help. and send me the link here if you post it. thanks.